# Keep getting 401 on authorization with SignalR

Tags: signalr, .net-6.0

I have been trying to create a sample Test app with SignalR but I have been extremely unsuccessful with authentication.

I am on .NET 6, and my Program.cs code looks like this.

**Program.cs**

```
using HubTestApp.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        // Identity made Cookie authentication the default.
        // However, we want JWT Bearer Auth to be the default.
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/";

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
        };

        // We have to hook the OnMessageReceived event in order to
        // allow the JWT authentication handler to read the access
        // token from the query string when a WebSocket or 
        // Server-Sent Events request comes in.

        // Sending the access token in the query string is required due to
        // a limitation in Browser APIs. We restrict it to only calls to the
        // SignalR hub in this code.
        // See https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security#access-token-logging
        // for more information about security considerations when using
        // the query string to transmit the access token.
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                // If the request is for our hub...
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                    (path.StartsWithSegments("/Test")))
                {
                    // Read the token out of the query string
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapHub<SimpleHub>("/Test");

app.Run();
```

**My hub code is pretty simple:**

```
namespace HubTestApp.Hubs
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

    internal class SimpleHub : Hub<ISimpleClient>
    {
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public async Task EchoMessage(string message) => await Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(message);
    }
}
```

**And this is my client code:**

```
namespace HubTestClient
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

    public class MockClient
    {
        private const string Token = "Bearer <JWT from AAD>";

        private readonly HubConnection hubConnection;

        public MockClient()
        {
            // Notice here I have tried to pass the token in various ways, all to no avail.
            this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl($"http://localhost:5110/Test?access_token={MockClient.Token}", options =>
                {
                    options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(MockClient.Token);
                    options.Headers.Add("Authorization", MockClient.Token);
                })
                .Build();

            this.hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", (message) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Received message: '{message}'");
            });
        }

        public async Task StartClient()
        {
            await hubConnection.StartAsync();

            Random rng  = new Random();

            while (true)
            {
                string messageToEcho = $"Sending random number '{rng.Next()}'";
                Console.WriteLine(messageToEcho);

                try
                {
                    await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("EchoMessage", messageToEcho);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

                // Delay 5 seconds between hitting the hub.
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I continuously get the message "Failed to invoke 'X' because user is unauthorized." I have made sure the token I got is valid. So, I'm bashing my head over this, completely confused where I am going wrong. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Enable this for tracing to know what's happening. `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` Also one question, when you tried the different ways of sending token, did you do them simultaneously? Could you do a clean send using only http://localhost:5110/Test and sending the token in options.Headers.Add("Authorization", MockClient.Token)

Comment: I added `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in both my client and server but I'm not sure where exactly I should be looking. And yes, I tried all those methods individually - all failed with that error.

Comment: Something else I've tried to do is put breakpoints inside the `OnMessageReceived` code, but I never see any sort of Authorization header being added when I use any auth method outside of adding it to the QSP. If in the QSP, then yes it's part of the URL, but even then the auth fails...

Comment: Use the header or access token factory, not both. And if you use the access token factory, remove "Bearer " from the string.